# CSS - Text set colour when over other colour (multiple colours)

Tags: html, css, colors

I would like to have some text that when it is over red, it changes to white, and when over grey, it changes to black. This image shows what I want to achieve. The text may go over onto more than one line.

[image]

**UPDATE:** I managed to get it working by using this code to set a gradient text colour:

```
  color:transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    #ffffff 0%,
    #ffffff 50%,
    #000000 50%,
    #000000 100%
  );
```

Comment: Don't post an answer in the question, post it as a self answer.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#red{
background-color:red;
color:white;
}
#grey{
background-color:grey;
color:black;
}
```

```html
<span id="red">this is my table</span><span id="grey">for students</span>
```

Comment: Thanks you! This really helped.

Comment: @marmadukeandbob are you sure this is really what you want? this is basically simple and trivial coloration using CSS

Comment: It is kind of what I want but I was looking to basically have the left half of a div one color and the other half another. Even if the mid line splits words

Comment: I mentioned to you in a previous comment that just drop in some code is not a good answer. Please have a second look at [answer].